# SailsJS Models: Dynamic recentHistory attribute of a model, how to implement

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I'm building a webapp and I have a model, lets call it "person" and "person" has an attribute "location." I want person to have another attribute, "recentHistory" that is an array with the last, say, 5 locations that the user has had. What is the best way to implement this? I've skimmed the docs and I'm not really sure. The frontend is in AngularJS if that matters (I don't think it should). Is the best implementation to use a beforeUpdate where if they are updating location, it adds it to that array (and pushes out the 3rd index of that array)?

Comment: I guess you can do something like 1-many relationship.. Sails uses an ORM called "Waterline" for its models.. See waterline's [documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) for further details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either store the data as an array or use associations. If you want to manage the array then the `beforeUpdate` lifecycle callback will be perfect.

Comment: But if I want to push into the array and not just overwrite it each time, won't I need to use afterUpdate?


Example:
Person.recentHistory = ['x','yy','zzz'];


When person's location changes to 'w', I want to push it into position 0 and and pop out 'zzz'.
If I use beforeUpdate, I don't actually have access to that information (size of the array or the actual element), no?